# Filter table using Regex like functionality

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-matching

I have an table on SQL Server which has two columns like below.

| OldValue | NewValue |
| --- | --- |
| ReqNo: 123456789 | ReqNo: 89898989 |
| RandomGibberish: , ReqNo: | RandomGibberish: , ReqNo: 12121212 |

I want to be able to filter the table if both the columns `OldValue` and `NewValue` start with **"ReqNo: "** followed by an 8 digit number and are an exact match to this pattern.

This would mean that the first row would be in my output but not the second row.

I know how to do this in python but still new to SQL Server and can't seem to find the right syntax.

Please help.

Comment: Note that the first record has an old value number which is _nine_, not eight, digits. Presumably this is just a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use SQL Server's enhanced `LIKE` operator here:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE OldValue LIKE 'ReqNo: [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' AND
      NewValue LIKE 'ReqNo: [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]';
```